# get grouped data from 2 tables with joins from oracle db using JSP

Tags: oracle, jsp, t-sql, join

I have three tables

`"congers(code_conger primary key,date_depart,date_retour,duree)"`

and

`"ouvriers_congers(#idouvrier, #idconger)"`

and

`"ouvriers(matricule,nom,prenom)"`

what I want is get the data from table congers with their OUVRIER "nom" and "prenom" and grouped by the idconger

```
     <% ResultSet rsS = st.executeQuery("select o.matricule,o.nom,o.prenom, c.*, oc.* from ouvriers o, congers c, ouvriers_conger oc where c.code_conger = oc.idconger and oc.idouvrier = o.matricule");

         while(rsS.next()){
         int cd = rsS.getInt("code_conger");
         %>
          <tr>
                        <td><%= cd %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getDate("date_depart") %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getDate("date_retour") %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getInt("duree") %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getString("nom") %></td>
          </tr>
                    <% } %>
```

but it show me the data like this

```
1    05/01/2015    05/05/2015   4    adil

1    05/01/2015    05/05/2015   4    souf

2    08/20/2015    08/30/2015   9    smith
```

as you see the result isn't groupped by the "code_conger"

I tried this to group it :

`select o.*, c.*, oc.idconger,oc.idouvrier from ouvriers o, congers c, ouvriers_conger oc where c.code_conger = oc.idconger and oc.idouvrier = o.matricule group by oc.idconger`

it give me an error : ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

the result I want to get is :

```
1    05/01/2015    05/05/2015   4    -adil
                                     -souf

2    08/20/2015    08/30/2015   9    smith
```

here is the DDL Statement for testing purpose

```
create table congers
(
  code_conger NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  date_depart DATE DEFAULT (sysdate),
  date_retour  DATE DEFAULT (sysdate),
  duree NUMBER(5)
);
create table ouvriers_congers
(
  idouvrier NUMBER(5), 
  idconger NUMBER(5),
  CONSTRAINT ouvriers_congers_pk PRIMARY KEY (idouvrier, idconger)
);
create table ouvriers
(
  matricule NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  nom VARCHAR2(15),
  prenom VARCHAR2(15)
);
INSERT INTO congers VALUES (1,to_date('05/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),
                    to_date('05/05/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),
                    4);
INSERT INTO congers  VALUES (2,to_date('08/20/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),
                    to_date('08/30/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),
                    9);
INSERT INTO ouvriers  VALUES (1,'adil','adil');
INSERT INTO ouvriers  VALUES (2,'souf','souf');
INSERT INTO ouvriers  VALUES (3,'smith','smith');
INSERT INTO ouvriers_congers  VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO ouvriers_congers  VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO ouvriers_congers  VALUES (3,2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self :

```
<tbody>
                    <%
                        Statement st2 = Connect.connecter();
                        ResultSet rsS = st.executeQuery("select * from congers");
                        while(rsS.next()){
                        int cd = rsS.getInt("code_conger");
                    %>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%= cd %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getDate("date_depart") %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getDate("date_retour") %></td>
                        <td><%= rsS.getInt("duree") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <%
                            ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select o.nom,o.prenom,o.matricule from ouvriers o,ouvriers_conger oc where oc.idconger = "+cd+" and oc.idouvrier = o.matricule");
                            while(rs2.next()){
                                out.print("- "+rs2.getString("nom")+" "+rs2.getString("prenom")+"<br />");
                            }
                            %>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:200px !important;"><center><a href="#"><img alt="Modifier" src="img/edit.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="delete.jsp?op=conge&id=<%= cd %>" style="margin-left:50px;"><img alt="Supprimer" src="img/delete.png" /></a></center></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }  %>
</tbody>
```

here I keep it here in case someone else needs it one day

Comment: "select * from congers" might become dangerous if your database gets big, you should find a way to limitate that or paginate it

Comment: I didn't use pagination ... because this will not be returning a big data (max 50 results or less)

Answer (score 0):

you can use LISTAGG from oracle: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

```
select 
  OC.IDCONGER,
  C.DATE_DEPART,
  C.DATE_RETOUR,
  C.DUREE,
  LISTAGG(o.nom||' '||O.PRENOM,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY O.NOM) AS ouvriers
FROM
  congers C,
  ouvriers_congers OC,
  ouvriers O
WHERE
  OC.IDCONGER = C.CODE_CONGER
  AND OC.idouvrier = O.matricule
group by (OC.idconger,C.DATE_DEPART,C.DATE_RETOUR,C.DUREE)
```

or use FOR XML in MSSQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms178107.aspx

or use GROUP_CONCAT() from mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

ps: you should paginate your data so you don't get 1203487187124 results when your database gets big

Comment: @ADiL hello man, i've tested the query and updated the answer. now it works